# How can I find all paths to access an java API?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, reverse-engineering

I'm analyzing an Android App, looking for security flaws. I've decompiled the APK with JEB and I found a vulnerable method in it.

My problem is: The App logic is too complex and it is very difficult to find a way to trigger this vulnerable method.

I would like to know if there exists a tool to find all the "paths" in the code to access some method.

For example, for the code below:

```
private void methodX() {
    // This is the method I want to call
}

private void methodA() {
    methodX();
}

private void methodB() {
    methodA();
}

private void methodC() {
    methodX();
}
```

The paths to access methodX are:

methodA( ) -> methodX( ) 
methodC( ) -> methodX( ) 
methodB( ) -> methodA( ) -> methodX( )

By the way, I'm using eclipse in the analysis, maybe there is some command on it to do this, but I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, Ctrl+Alt+H will open the call hierarchy for a method, showing a tree view you can expand for finding "indirect" references to that method.

Here is an example tracing a method from Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet`:
[image]

Comment: The same comment above, I also want indirect references (Like methodB -> methodA -> methodX) and this only gives to me direct references.

Comment: The call hierarchy is a tree view that will show you callers of callers _ad infinitum_ (or at least as far as Eclipse can analyze). Can you explain why you think you will not see `methodB` using this?

Comment: The problem is that my input is the endpoint, not the start point. I want to query for methodX and it should return to me the start points (methodA, methodB, methodC). The question I want to answer is: "How can I access one specific method?"

Comment: This example _is_ the endpoint. In the screenshot, `initMultipartResolver` is the equivalent to your `methodX`. The tree shows all the callers ("start points") that will eventually call the `initMultipartResolver` method.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry. Unfortunately this is not working here, I suspect it is because the project is a decompiled APK (contains a lot of errors and the build has failed). I'll continue to do it manually, but I think you deserve the solved problem flag ;) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Shift+G on methodX() will show you all references

Comment: Yes, but I also want indirect references (Like methodB -> methodA -> methodX) and this only gives to me direct references.